# Insert image into database using buildin function in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, image, dreamweaver

I want to insert image into database using the following query. This is the part of the example of query.

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
         $image = mysql_real_escape_string($image);
          $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO company (Name, GSTNo, GSTRegDate, RegNo, Address1, Address2, Address3,Address4, PostCode, City,
           CountryID, StateID,  TelNo, FaxNo, Website, Email, CustomerLogo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,$image)",
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Name'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSTNo'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSTRegDate'], "date"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['RegNo'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address1'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address2'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address3'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address4'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Postcode'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['City'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['country'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['State'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Tel'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fax'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Website'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"));
```

For the customerLogo, how should I type to insert the image? I tried before using
GetSQLValueString($_POST['image'], "longblob")); but seems it cant works.

HTML( for the upload picture)

```
  <tr>
        <td align="right">
        <label><strong>Image:</strong></label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image" ><br>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
```

and there is a button to click and insert.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of storing images is by storing them directly on disk and saving just the location in your database.

Here's an example:

```
$image = uniqid() . '.jpg';
file_put_contents($image, $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO company (Name, GSTNo, GSTRegDate, RegNo, Address1, Address2, Address3,Address4, PostCode, City,
           CountryID, StateID,  TelNo, FaxNo, Website, Email, CustomerLogo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,$image)",
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Name'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSTNo'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSTRegDate'], "date"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['RegNo'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address1'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address2'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address3'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address4'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Postcode'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['City'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['country'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['State'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Tel'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fax'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Website'], "text"),
                               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"));
```

You might also want to check for the MIME and make sure that you only let the user upload images and serve them with the correct extension (jpg, png, gif etc.).